# Query to retrieve names of group nodes

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

If I had some XML such as this loaded into an XDocument object:

```
<Root>
    <GroupA>
        <Item attrib1="aaa" attrib2="000" />
    </GroupA>
    <GroupB>
        <Item attrib1="bbb" attrib2="111" />
        <Item attrib1="ccc" attrib2="222" />
        <Item attrib1="ddd" attrib2="333" />
    </GroupB>
    <GroupC>
        <Item attrib1="eee" attrib2="444" />
        <Item attrib1="fff" attrib2="555" />
    </GroupC>
</Root>
```

What would a query look like to retrieve the names of the group nodes?

For example, I'd like a query to return:

```
GroupA
GroupB
GroupC
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this:

```
XDocument doc; // populate somehow

// this will give the names as XName
var names = from child in doc.Root.Elements()
            select child.Name;

// if you want just the local (no-namespaces) name as a string, use this
var simpleNames = from child in doc.Root.Elements()
                  select child.Name.LocalName;
```